# Can i write php code in .htacces file?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need to redirect the url which is accessing the site images to the appropriate contents section of the site for example . the image test.jpg is used in the section http://www.mysite.com/article1 and my image path is domain/images/test.jpg if any user browse the image directly by this url domain/images/test.jpg . i would like to redirect to the article section.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is kind of working against the principles of the web.  A web browser loads that image of yours the same way if someone reads the article as it does when somebody accesses the image "directly".

If you only want to disable access to browsing your image collection, i.e. the directory listing of the images, that's fine and you can easily disable that in your web server.

However -- and I think that's what you are trying to do -- if you try to find out the difference how somebody accesses an image, either while reading "article1" or by loading it "directly", then things get complicated.  You *could* use some kludges like setting cookies in the article and that you check for when loading the image...  But it is probably more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Not that much trouble, though. Just 2 RewriteCond's on referer